# Rostest succeeds test if a node crashes

Tags: rostest, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a node in a test-case crashed, rostest doesn't care about it, and succeeds the testcase.

For example:

```
$ rostest somepkg basic.test
... logging to /home/parallels/.ros/log/rostest-parallels-vm-6224.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/parallels/.ros/test_results/somepkg/rostest-test_basic.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/catkin_ws/src/somepkg/src/fail.py", line 3, in <module>
    print 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
[Testcase: testbasic_test] ... ok

[ROSTEST]-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[clever.rosunit-basic_test/test_state][passed]

SUMMARY
 * RESULT: SUCCESS
 * TESTS: 1
 * ERRORS: 0
 * FAILURES: 0

rostest log file is in /home/parallels/.ros/log/rostest-parallels-vm-6224.log
```

How to make rostest fail the test if a node crashes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327424/rostest-succeeds-test-if-a-node-crashes/) by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, to make the nodes "required" is kind of a solution.

---

Originally posted by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) with karma: 11 on 2019-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't tell for certain without looking at your test case definition, but the following error you're seeing is what `fail.py` (and/or underlining modules) returned, not your test case.

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Unless at least one of your test cases finish with certain error state, `rostest` passes.

Writing test cases is covered on [wiki.ros.org/rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2019-07-04**:
Yeah, but it doesn't make sense. If one of my nodes just has fallen, why in the world we can consider that our tests are successful?

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2019-07-04**:
Actually, I found kind of solution, if a "required" node falls, then tests fall too. The only problem is that I don't want to make all of nodes "required" in my launch-files I want to test.